# Notebook Screen replacement

Tags: laptop

i have a samsung notebook and it's screen broken couse of physical impact. I have also 2 asus , 1 toshiba and 1 hp notebook screens. Is it possible to replace hp/asus/toshiba etc. (different product) screen panels to samsung notebook or do i need the same model product screen ?

Comment: You need a compatible part and that is very unlikely coming from different manufacturers.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it is not possible to swap the LCD panels.

The longer answer is *maybe*.  Computer manufacturers do not make their LCD panels, but purchase them from third parties.  It is entirely possible that a panel found in another laptop, either from the same manufacturer or another are identical, or similar enough, that it could be swapped in.  The problem with this is identifying which panels work with driver boards.  There simply is no easy method to do this.  You could spend hours on researching and find no answer whatsoever.  Its just not worth the hassle.